# Devexpress GridVIew restore layout

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using the RestoreLayoutFromStream() method to reset my GridView Layout. This works well, but is lost the selection.

There is other some method to restoring layout and that does not get lost the selection?

Comment: you mean you lose rows selection?

Comment: Yes, but I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
var srcIndex = this.gridview.GetDataSourceRowIndex(this.gridview.FocusedRowHandle);

{...} -> gridView.RestoreLayoutFromStream(memoryStream);

this.gridview.FocusedRowHandle = this.gridview.GetRowHandle(srcIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Selection is not the grid layout. It's not saved to a layout file/stream. Use the approach provided in the [T239643](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T239643) ticket on DevExpress Support Center to resolve the issue.